# return two dimensional array from function with non-traditional signature in C

Tags: c

I was training C on this kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/54d7660d2daf68c619000d95/c and got stuck by a strange signature of the function: 
`long long (*get_res(long long lst[][2], int row, long long LCD))[2]`

Here is how I create and malloc my array:

```
long long (*get_res(long long lst[][2], int row, long long LCD))[2]
{
    long long **res;
    long long mul = 0;

    res = (long long **)malloc(sizeof(long long *) * row);
    if (!res)
        return (NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        res[i] = (long long *)malloc(sizeof(long long) * 2);
        mul = LCD / lst[i][1];
        res[i][0] = lst[i][0] * mul;
        res[i][1] = lst[i][1] * mul;
    }
    return ((long long(*)[2])res);
}
```

Then I return the result of this function in the main function like this:

`return (get_res(lst, row, LCD));`

And I get some strange results on the tests. I've already checked all the calculations: they work just as  expected. Here's how the tester decided to get the result of the function (yet another point that I don't understand):

```
    long long data[3][2] = { {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4} };
    dotest(data, 3, "{{6, 12},{4, 12},{3, 12}}");
    ...
    void dotest(long long a[][2], int row, char* sexpr) 
    {    
    long long* act = convertFrac(a, row);
    char* sdat = array2D2StringInt(a, row, 2);
    char* sact = array2D2StringInt((long long(*)[2])act, row, 2);
    //some checking
    }
```

So here are the questions: 
1. What should I do to make the program work as expected? 
2. Why would you opt for this signature instead of a classic  `type **Func_name(params)`  ?

Comment: By "non-traditional" do you really mean "unnecessarily confusing"?

Comment: Tip: Instead of `long long` just say what you mean, like `int64_t`.

Comment: @tadman yup, that's what I mean

Comment: The main problem is that you lie to the compiler and tell it you'll return a pointer to a 2D array. But you malloc a fragmented look-up table thing, which is not a 2D array. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You choose to return a pointer to `long long[2]`, so you should allocate an array of `long long[2]`, not `long long*`.

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

```
long long (*get_res(long long lst[][2], int row, long long LCD))[2]
{
    long long (*res)[2];
    long long mul = 0;

    res = malloc(sizeof(*res) * row);
    if (!res)
        return (NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        mul = LCD / lst[i][1];
        res[i][0] = lst[i][0] * mul;
        res[i][1] = lst[i][1] * mul;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I don't get one thing: do we still allocate the whole array on the heap? Because this half-static declaration makes me think that we don't...

Comment: @IgorPetrov What `malloc()` gets is an integer to determine the size to allocate. It won't care how the integer is calculated and return some resion on the heap (if successful).

Comment: `res = malloc( sizeof(long long[row][2]) );` might be easier to read. And returning the array by parameter might be easier to read too: `void get_res (int row, long long (**lst)[row][2]) { ... *lst = res; }`